# Efficient algorithm to merge rows of a table based on matching items from a list in a column

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, merge, time-complexity

I am trying to complete a task as part of a larger project at my workplace and I have a working solution for the problem, but due to the time complexity of the solution it takes a infeasibly long time to complete the task (the length of the dataframe is several millions). It is not a one-time task and has to be run daily.

Objective: Given a table with two columns: 'a' and 'b' where 'a' has single strings as values and 'b' has a list of strings as values, merge rows where an item in 'b' of a row matches with an item in 'b' of other rows such that 'a' and 'b' in the merged table would both be a list of items.

Example 1:

Input Table:

```
   a          b
0  1  [a, b, e]
1  2     [a, g]
2  3     [c, f]
3  4        [d]
4  5        [b]
```

Required Output:

```
           a             b
0  [1, 2, 5]  [a, b, e, g]
1        [3]        [c, f]
2        [4]           [d]
```

Example 2:

Input Table:

```
   a          b
0  1  [a, b, e]
1  3  [a, g, f]
2  4     [c, f]
3  6     [d, h]
4  9  [b, g, h]
```

Required Output:

```
                 a                         b
0  [1, 3, 4, 6, 9]  [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

The working solution I have:

```
import pandas as pd

def merge_rows(df):
    df_merged = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    matched = False
    while len(df) > 0:
        if not matched:
            x = len(df_merged)
            df_merged.loc[x, 'a'] = list(df.iloc[0, 0])
            df_merged.loc[x, 'b'] = df.iloc[0, 1]
            df = df.iloc[1:, :]
        for rm in range(len(df_merged)):
            matched = False
            right_b_lists_of_lists = df.b.tolist()
            df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
            match_index_list = [i for b_part in df_merged.loc[rm, 'b'] for (i, b_list) in enumerate(right_b_lists_of_lists) if b_part in b_list]
            df_matches = df.loc[match_index_list]
            if len(df_matches) > 0:
                df_merged.loc[rm, 'a'] = list(set(df_merged.loc[rm, 'a'] + df_matches.a.tolist()))
                df_merged.loc[rm, 'b'] = list(set(df_merged.loc[rm, 'b'] + [item for sublist in df_matches.b.tolist() for item in sublist]))
                df = df.drop(df_matches.index)
                matched = True
                break
    return df_merged

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'b': [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'g'], ['c', 'f'], ['d'], ['b']]})
df1_merged = merge_rows(df1)
print('Original DF:')
print(df1.to_string())
print('Merged DF:')
print(df1_merged.to_string())

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '3', '4', '6', '9'], 'b': [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'g', 'f'], ['c', 'f'], ['d', 'h'], ['b', 'g', 'h']]})
df2_merged = merge_rows(df2)
print('Original DF:')
print(df2.to_string())
print('Merged DF:')
print(df2_merged.to_string())
```

The above code prints the following:

```
Original DF:
   a          b
0  1  [a, b, e]
1  2     [a, g]
2  3     [c, f]
3  4        [d]
4  5        [b]

Merged DF:
           a             b
0  [1, 2, 5]  [e, b, a, g]
1        [3]        [c, f]
2        [4]           [d]

Original DF:
   a          b
0  1  [a, b, e]
1  3  [a, g, f]
2  4     [c, f]
3  6     [d, h]
4  9  [b, g, h]

Merged DF:
                 a                         b
0  [4, 3, 6, 9, 1]  [e, h, c, g, f, d, b, a]
```

Note that the lists in 'a' and 'b' in the output from the above code are not sorted, but that is acceptable.

This solution is practically infeasible given the asymptotic time complexity of O(n^2) as average case for the solution, along with being unable to think of a way to parallelise this polynomial solution, the large size of n that I need to run it on a daily basis, and the machine I have to run it on.

Any help with either a *linearithmic solution* **or** a *parallelisable polynomial solution* (or better!) would be greatly appreciated!

A solution is Python is preferred, but I would welcome a solution in R / C / C++ / Java / P.

Comment: I think this is essentially the disjoint set union problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).  I don't have a solution, but this algorithm could get you better time complexity.

Comment: Do you have a dataset that takes around 30 seconds to run for testing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation using the idea of the disjoint set structure.
Note that there are many ways to make it more efficient (and there could be bugs too).
At least it works on the two cases, and runs 10x faster than the original function in the question post on my laptop.

```py
import pandas as pd

def merge_rows2(df):
    parents = {}   # maps elements to the parent member
    
    for row in df.values:
        elems = row[1]
        if len(elems) < 1:
            continue  # edge case, empty letter list
        for elem in elems:
            if not elem in parents:       # new letter
                parents[elem] = elems[0]  # register the first element as the parent
            else:   # this letter has already be seen
                # find the root parent
                p = parents[elem]
                path = [elem]
                while True:
                    path.append(p)
                    if p == parents[p]:
                        break
                    p = parents[p]
                # map to the new parent, two sets merged
                parents[p] = elems[0]
                # path compression, for fast access next time
                for e in path:
                    parents[e] = elems[0]
    #print(parents)  # debug
    
    # make sure all elements directly maps to the root
    for e, p in parents.items():
        if e == p:  # root node
            continue
        # find the root node
        path = [e]
        while True:
            path.append(p)
            if p == parents[p]:
                break
            p = parents[p]
        # path compression
        for e in path:
            parents[e] = p
    #print(parents)  # debug
    groups = {}
    for e, p in parents.items():
        if p in groups:
            groups[p].append(e)
        else:
            groups[p] = [e]
    #print(groups)  # debug
    # collect values
    values = {g:[] for g in groups}
    for row in df.values:
        elems = row[1]
        if len(elems) < 1:
            continue
        p = parents[elems[0]]  # group identity
        values[p].append(row[0])
    # make data frame
    rows = [{"a":values[g], "b":groups[g]} for g in groups]
    return pd.DataFrame(rows) 

# test
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'b': [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'g'], ['c', 'f'], ['d'], ['b']]})
print(merge_rows2(df1))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '3', '4', '6', '9'], 'b': [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'g', 'f'], ['c', 'f'], ['d', 'h'], ['b', 'g', 'h']]})
print(merge_rows2(df2))
```

```py
# test
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'b': [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'g'], ['c', 'f'], ['d'], ['b']]})
print(merge_rows2(df1))
#           a             b
#0  [1, 2, 5]  [a, b, e, g]
#1        [3]        [c, f]
#2        [4]           [d]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '3', '4', '6', '9'], 'b': [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'g', 'f'], ['c', 'f'], ['d', 'h'], ['b', 'g', 'h']]})
print(merge_rows2(df2))
#                 a                         b
#0  [1, 3, 4, 6, 9]  [a, b, e, g, f, c, d, h]
```

```py
%timeit merge_rows(df1)
%timeit merge_rows2(df1)
#7.47 ms ± 277 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#365 µs ± 3.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit merge_rows(df2)
%timeit merge_rows2(df2)
#4.1 ms ± 90.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#351 µs ± 14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks much! I will get to try this on Monday.

Comment: Disjoint sets makes total sense! I am wondering why I dint think about MSTs earlier. Thanks for the help. I will post results once I am able to try this at work.

Comment: @Kota Mori: Your routine is fast! I did a rewrite to learn the algo and randomly generated big data to test and compare it with other routines here: https://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2020/07/algorithms-datastructures-faster.html and later here: https://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2020/07/more-constrained-random-testing-of-set.html

Answer (score 1):

This uses pure Python rather than Pandas but might need a more representative example dataset to truly see which is faster as it makes heavy use of dicts and sets which has different time and memory use characteristics.

The `consolidation` function I copied from my [Set consolidation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation) task on Rosetta Code.

### Code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Answering:
        "Efficient algorithm to merge rows of a table based on matching items from a list in a column"
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817492/efficient-algorithm-to-merge-rows-of-a-table-based-on-matching-items-from-a-list
        
Created on Fri Jul 10 04:49:26 2020

@author: Paddy3118
"""
#%%
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint as pp

def consolidate(sets):
    setlist = [s for s in sets if s]
    for i, s1 in enumerate(setlist):
        if s1:
            for s2 in setlist[i+1:]:
                intersection = s1.intersection(s2)
                if intersection:
                    s2.update(s1)
                    s1.clear()
                    s1 = s2
    return [s for s in setlist if s]

#%%
dat1 = {'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
        'b': [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'g'], 
              ['c', 'f'], ['d'], ['b']]}

dat2 = {'a': ['1', '3', '4', '6', '9'], 
        'b': [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'g', 'f'], 
              ['c', 'f'], ['d', 'h'], ['b', 'g', 'h']]}
#data = dat2

def row_merge(data):
    data['a'] = [set(x) for x in data['a']]
    data['b'] = [set(x) for x in data['b']]
    
    b_map = defaultdict(list)
    for i, b_list in enumerate(data['b']):
        for item in b_list:
            b_map[item].append(i)
    
    index_merge = consolidate([set(v) for v in b_map.values()])
    
    a, b = defaultdict(set), defaultdict(set)
    a, b = [], []
    adata, bdata = data['a'], data['b']
    
    for merge in index_merge:
        arow, brow = set(), set()
        for row_index in merge:
            arow |= adata[row_index]
            brow |= bdata[row_index]
        a.append(sorted(arow))
        b.append(sorted(brow))
    
    return {'a': a, 'b': b}


answer = row_merge(dat1)
pp(answer)
answer = row_merge(dat2)
pp(answer)
```

### Output

```
{'a': [['1', '2', '5'], ['3'], ['4']],
 'b': [['a', 'b', 'e', 'g'], ['c', 'f'], ['d']]}
{'a': [['1', '3', '4', '6', '9']],
 'b': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]}
```

Comment: Thanks much! I will get to try this on Monday.

Comment: Interesting solution. Trying it out on my dataset at work may take time. When I do, I will update the results. In any case, I appreciate a new way to think about it.